# Can we change the resolution of image within seqtreedisplay() function call?

Tags: r, traminer

I am generating tree images with the seqtreedisplay() function from the R package TraMineR but the default resolution is 72 dpi. I need to create 300 dpi image. Is it be possible do it within the  seqtreedisplay() function call using like a "res" argument?

Thanks for help

Comment: Add the code which you've written till now.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the resolution of the output file produced by the `seqtreedisplay` function by passing a `device.args` argument (that will be treated as an element of the  `...` list).

The `device.args` argument should be a list of arguments that will be passed to the used device (`jpeg` when `image.format="jpg"`, and `png` otherwise).

To get a 300 dpi resolution, you need to set `res=300`, but also to increase the the `width` and `height`.

I illustrate with the `mvad` data:

```
data(mvad)
## Defining a state sequence object
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86])

## Growing a seqtree using Hamming distances:
seqt <- seqtree(mvad.seq~ male + Grammar + funemp + gcse5eq + fmpr + livboth,
                data=mvad, R=1000, pval=0.05, seqdist.arg=list(method="HAM"))

## Generating the plot as a 300 dpi image in mytree.jpg
seqtreedisplay(seqt, filename = "mytree.jpg", type="d", border=NA, image.format = "jpg", 
      device.args=list(width=480*300/72, height=480*300/72, res=300))
```

---

**Below is my previous answer that does not work because `seqtreedisplay` internally first generates texts and plots in bitmap format before saving them in the `image.format`.**

---

A solution would be to select a vectorial format (e.g. pdf or eps) for the outcome of seqtreedisplay and then to convert this vectorial file into a raster format with the desired resolution.

Assuming you have installed `ImageMagick` (and `Gostscript` on which `ImageMagick` relies to convert to/from pdf or eps), you could use the `convert.g` function of `TraMineRextras` for this conversion. I illustrate below using the `mvad`data:

```
## Drawing the tree as a pdf file and converting into jpeg
seqtreedisplay(seqt, filename = "mytree.pdf", type="d", border=NA, image.format = "pdf")
path <- getwd() ## retrieve the path
convert.g(path = path, fileroot = "mytree", from = "pdf", to = "jpeg",
          options = "-units PixelsPerInch -density 300x300")
```

The resulting jpeg file will be in a `jpeg` subdirectory of the current folder.

Comment: I edited the answer because the first solution proposed does actually not work as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much Gilbert ! The second solution works perfect for me. Indeed I could not used the first solution and was converting into GIMP but I was not really satisfied.